# Property with File type log-able, but undefined returned when trying to access said property from a prototype function

Tags: javascript, file

I am trying to validate if the file uploaded using `input type = "file"` is an image file or not in the following example:

```js
function UploadImageProcess(ImageFile) {
  this.file = ImageFile;
  //... some other things
}

UploadImageProcess.prototype.fileTypeValidation = () => this.file.type.startsWith('image/') ? true : false;

//Other prototype methods

let target = document.getElementById('test');
target.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let file = target.files[0];
  let newProcess = new UploadImageProcess(file);
  console.log(newProcess);
  console.log(newProcess.fileTypeValidation());
});
```

```html
<input id = "test" type = "file" accept = "image/*">
```

As you can see from my `console.log(newProcess)`, my `newProcess` already contains the property `file` and yet when my prototype method tries to access said property, it says that it's undefined. What's the problem here?

Comment: It's not a prototype *method* since you used arrow function syntax.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, sorry, I do not know the correct terminology for it. What is it called?

Comment: I mean it should be a prototype method, but that [arrow functions cannot be used as methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

becuse you use arrow function and bind to the wrong `this`, change it to normal function.

```
UploadImageProcess.prototype.fileTypeValidation = function(){
   return this.file.type.startsWith('image/')
}
```

---

reply to comment, you can also bind `this` in constructor (not really the same thing, though)

```
function UploadImageProcess(ImageFile) {
  this.file = ImageFile;
  this.fileTypeValidation = () => this.file.type.startsWith('image/');
}
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way to maintain the use of arrow function, but binding the `this` to the appropriate context?

Comment: @RichardW yes in some way, see my update.

Comment: i see. I want the method to be on `prototype` though because I do not want to redeclare the functions for each time I change my picture that I select.